# Preapre string with special characters

Tags: excel, string, vb.net

I am taking columns names from excel sheet and one of the column names which I am getting is as follows:

```
Recorded by" & vbLf & "FO Staff
```

For all excel columns names I have a list in my program to reflect all in excel to check if they match or not. However only that column giving me mentioned string. The problem is I don't know how to prepare my string to have same as text for comparison. Simply saying how to prepare string to get exactly the string I shown above? If possible with explanation.

**EDIT:**
Didn't mentioned about one thing. I store all reflected values in xml config file. I serialize columns names (the same column values as in excel). My program deserialize xml file and load array of that items. Then that array is compared to the array of excel columns which are comming directly from excel.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Is your Excel column name split over 2 lines? Do you need to add a `vbLf` to your string to check for a match?

Comment: @AFriend I am taking the values of all columns from excel to an array of strings. One of those columns string is the one i shown you. In my program i have a list of strings which reflects same values as i have in the array from excel so then i have to put for that column same text for correct comparmission. Hope now is clear bit more

Answer (score 1):

To get the exact string in your question, you need to double up the double quotes:

```
Dim colText = "Recorded by"" & vbLf & ""FO Staff"
```

EDIT:

It's not elegant, but to remove double quotes from the deserialised string:

```
colText.Replace("""""", """")
```

Comment: @A Friend: Very sorry i forgot to mentioned one thing - see in main post (Edit). If i serialize your value for that column it will be shown in xml node like this:  <string>Recorded by" &amp; vbLf &amp; "FO Staff</string> then when i deserialize it to string again it looks like this: Recorded by"" & vbLf & ""FO Staff  so means when i compare to excel column name from main post we have two more double quotes. Hope you get the point.

Comment: @A Friend how about that?

Comment: @A Firend Note that i dont want to manipualte this value from code, but just save it to xml, then extract and compare. How to prepare that text to xml and then after extract from xml to be the same value as excel value? Thanks

Comment: Well it's being serialized fine, its just when it gets deserialised that you have the issue. So you need to account for that when you deserialise. There's no preparation you can do, because then you're serialising an incorrect value.

Comment: @A Friend ok so when i use your colText and then serialize it will be saved in xml as : Recorded by" &amp; vbLf &amp; "FO Staff   then when deserialize and use your replacment i get finally: Recorded by"" & vbLf & ""FO Staff    so it is still bit diffrence comparing to excel cell from main post.

Comment: Check before and after the replacement, it worked in my testing

Comment: Yes, I saw. But I can't replicate anymore. I can perfectly serialise and deserialise and it comes out in the same format, without even needing the replacement. I checked the equality and it's fine.

Comment: @A Friend Hmm i will check again later let you know